# Detecting and logging phone call answer and phone call drop events?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone

I would like to know if its possible to detect and register an incoming call and also to register a droped call?

After doing a bit of research, I noticed a lot of comments on using the obscured event.

But problem here is that this event is not specific to phone calls and therefore the data collected will not be accurate.

Is there a way to verify which of the obscured events are actual incomming calls or dropped calls?

If this is possible, could you please respond with a sample code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

no there is no way to plug into phone call related events as there isn't any available option.

Answer (score 2):

The current Windows Phone SDK (version 7.1.1) doesn't allow you to access any information about received/dropped calls, nor their log information...

I guess that you'd have to use do with Interop access to achieve such a thing, but that is always tricky!

Comment: I wouldn't mention interop - 3rd party dev's aren't allowed for starters + you dont want to push more devs towards homebrew

Comment: Why not? Although I'm not doing any homebrew, I've seen some pretty amazing projects floating around the internet (like one on Folders in the menu and tiles)

Comment: are those made by 3rd party devs ? or are those example only or done by OEMs / TELCOS or microsoft itself ? are those allowed in marketplace? Folder apps in a homebrew app that isn't on marketplace